# Is it possible to write non-game cross-platform 3D visualization mobile app developed using xamarin form (UI) and Unity (3D part)?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, xamarin.ios, xamarin

We want to develop cross platform 3D visualization app. The app will have 3D part which we intend to develop in unity and rest of the app (UI ) to be developed using Xamarin Forms.

Is this viable ? If not what alternative approach we should take here ?

Comment: What does Unity say? Since they use Xamarin technologies, their word should be a simple answer for you. P.S. You are missing what platforms you are targeting.

Comment: Whether this is possible can be answered by making a simple test. If it's viable is up to you to judge since only you know all the requirements for the app.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this viable ?

No. While they both use Mono as their base, they are very different Mono version (IIRC Unity ships something based on Mono 2.6, while the current XI stable ships 3.8).

Even if the runtime were identical several instances of it cannot safely coexists in a single process. Sadly having separate executables (inside a single app) is not an option for some operating systems, like iOS.

> If not what alternative approach we should take here ?

- iOS8 added support for [SceneKit](http://blog.xamarin.com/3d-in-ios-8-with-scene-kit/) which could be used for 3D visualization. This is an identical API that is available on OSX (if this is also a targeted platform).
- Using OpenGL[ES] would be another, more cross platform, technology to use for 3D visualization.